# How do I play a video with audio from a separate file? (mux during playback)

Tags: video-player, avconv

My laptop runs Xubuntu 14.04 LTS. I'm composing a score for a silent film, and I'm trying to ["Mickey Mouse" it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mickey_Mousing) (synchronize notes to the action). I can tweak the silent film's editing slightly to line up events with beats of the music. The tool for making the film renders to a lossless intermediate (AVI with Huffyuv) at about 1 GB per two minutes, which I can encode to a compressed format (WebM with VP8 or MPEG-4 with AVC).

If I've already encoded the video, I normally use this command line to combine the compressed video with the score, based on [avconv replace audio](http://nova.deviator.si/development-log/avconv-replace-audio):

```
avconv -y -i the_video.mp4 -i the_audio.wav -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -c:v copy -c:a libvo_aacenc -ac 1 -ab 48000 -t 120 result.mp4
avplay result.mp4
```

Because the lossless intermediate is gigabytes in size, I don't want to use `-c:v copy` to copy those gigabytes every time I want to check my changes. Nor do I want to encode every time because my laptop's CPU (Atom N450, 1 core 2 threads) is too slow to encode full-size video in real time. But when I try to use a similar command line to play instead of encoding:

```
avplay -i the_video.avi -i sound/sticks.wav -map 0:0 -map 1:0
```

I get the following error message:

```
avplay version 9.18-6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, Copyright (c) 2003-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Mar 16 2015 13:20:58 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
Argument 'sound/sticks.wav' provided as input filename, but 'hyf_enc.mp4' was already specified.
```

Google `"avplay" "was already specified"` produced only source code results, not workarounds. I tried `"ffplay" "was already specified"` as well, but most pages with questions about that were related to overlaying a PNG, not muxing.

How should I play one file's audio and another file's video, with seeking linked between the two, without having to remux them to a file on the disk? Would a player in Ubuntu's repositories other than `avplay` work well for this? Or should I just shrink the lossless intermediate in order to make remuxing practical?

Answer (score 0):

My knowledge is based on the `ffmpeg` and `ffplay` tools which I understand to be replaced by `avconv` and `avplay` on Ubuntu which are supposed to be functionally equivalent (let's not debate on how far that functional equivalence goes).

I don't think the *play* tools accept multiple inputs. You can stream via a pipe from `ffmpeg` (er, `avconv`) into `ffplay` (`avplay`). Try this:

```
$ avconv -i the_video.avi -i sound/sticks.wav -map 0:0 -map 1:0 - | avplay -
```

The above is a guess based on your question but it's based on my own real example which I've pasted below just as a reference (yes I am using the `ffmpeg` and `ffplay` tools) :

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -i hw:0,2 -f v4l2 -i /dev/video0 -f avi pipe:1 | ffplay -
```

Comment: I tried that and got `pipe:: Invalid data found when processing input`

Comment: On my Arch Linux system the command line `ffmpeg -f alsa -i hw:0,2 -f v4l2 -i /dev/video0  -f avi - | ffplay -` opens a window with video and audio in it. I have ffmpeg 2.4.2. You need the final `-f avi` to specify a container format for the stream otherwise `ffplay` won't be able to process it.

Comment: `avconv -i video.avi -i audio.wav -f avi - | avplay -` gave `pipe:: Operation not permitted`

Comment: Ah well, sorry not to be able to help. You could always get the proper "ffmpeg" (which the [latest Ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=names&keywords=ffmpeg) has switched back to).

Comment: How would I go about getting proper FFmpeg? Upgrading from 14.04 LTS to 15.04 through 14.10 is [off-topic](http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) because 14.10 is more than 9 months old and not an LTS, and skipping a release is "highly __not recommended__" according to answers to [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading).

Comment: One option is to get it from [upstream](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html#LinuxBuilds). There's a link from there to [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/trusty-media) that has static precompiled binaries for 14.04. It looks just what you'd want but you're on your own really - I use Arch Linux myself.